# SELinux doesn't let me allow ftpd

Tags: selinux, vsftpd, alma-linux

I'm in AlmaLinuxOS 9.

When I try to run `setsebool -P ftpd_full_access on` , it sends me a message saying boolean `ftpd_full_access not defined`.

I don't know how could I make it working nor what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the boolean is incorrect.

The correct command should be `setsebool -P allow_ftpd_full_access 1`

Here is documentation:

- https://linux.die.net/man/8/ftpd_selinux
- https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/ftpd_selinux.8.html

Comment: To pass on advice given to me; die.net hasn't been updated since 2017. Here's a link to an active online man page site: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/ :-)

Comment: @Peregrino69 the documentation has not really changed for this since what seems to be 2005 being the oldest documentation I found. I added another documentation link from Ubuntu Jammy which appears the documentation was last updated around 2021

Comment: Oh no, that wasn't my point, like I said just passing on advice given to me :-)